# Windows 7 / XP Dual boot - Switch Remotely

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot

I have a Windows 7 x64 and a Windows XP 32-bit Dual boot system, with the Windows 7 Boot manager loaded.

Windows 7 is currently setup as the default OS, thus it will start to Windows 7 if no option is selected after 30 seconds.

I'm going to work remotely on the PC, and will sometimes be required to switch to the Windows XP installed to do some work. I can accomplish this by going managing the Boot order in the Windows 7 and set the Windows XP as the default boot partition, so that when I reboot my Windows 7 remotely, the Windows XP will be the default option that gets loaded after 30 seconds.

This all works well.

How do I from Windows XP, set the Windows 7 Bootmanager to set the Windows 7 partition as the default partition, so that when I reboot the PC, that Windows 7 is loaded after the 30 seconds, instead of Windows XP?

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test this right now, but [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) should be able to handle the switch from XP also.

Comment: +1; that was going to be my first thought, but I also cannot test due to the lack of an 7/XP dual boot system.

Comment: I will download and have a look.

Comment: I've downloaded EasyBCD, and after a couple of tries got it to work. Downloaded iReboot from the creators of EasyBCD as well to easily switch between which OS I want to start up the next time the PC reboots. Thanks for the link.